# How to get accessible camera resolutions?

Tags: silverlight, camera, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, resolution

I would like to ask, how it is possible to get all accessible camera resolutions in Windows Phone 8.1 app (for both silverlight and WinRT). I wanted to use:

```
Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(
     Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.CameraSensorLocation.Back);
```

But I am getting message that namespace Windows.Phone.Media.Capture is obsolete and may not be supported from next version of Windows Phone starting with Windows Phone Blue and that I should use Windows.Media.Capture instead. However Windows.Media.Capture does not allow me to get accessible camera resolutions, so I would like to ask, how to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done like this:

First let's define method to get *Device ID* which will be used to take a photo:

```
private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredCamera)
{
    DeviceInformation deviceID = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredCamera);

    if (deviceID != null) return deviceID;
    else throw new Exception(string.Format("Camera of type {0} doesn't exist.", desiredCamera));
}
```

Then after we initialize the camera - we can read the resolutions like this:

```
private async void InitCameraBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
    captureManager = new MediaCapture();

    await captureManager.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
            PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview,
            AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
            VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
        });
    // Get resolutions
    var resolutions = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Select(x => x as VideoEncodingProperties).ToList();
    // get width and height:
    uint width = resolutions[0].Width;
    uint height = resolutions[0].Height;
}
```